# Router doesn't get response from database functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when running the app and testing the /signup route the data gets written to the db and i can console.log it from the database/models.js file, but in the routes/index.js file it returns "Something went wrong." and postman shows nothing, not even an empty array or object.

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const database = require('../database/models');


router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.email || !isValidEmail(req.body.email))
        res.status(400).send('Email invalid.');
    else if (!req.body.username || !isValidCredential(req.body.username) || !req.body.password || !isValidCredential(req.body.password))
        res.status(400).send('Username/password invalid.');
    else {
        const result = database.createUser(req.body.email, req.body.username, req.body.password);
        if (result)
            res.status(200).send(result);
        else 
            res.send('Something went wrong.');
    }
});

function isValidEmail (email) {
    if (email.match("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function isValidCredential (credential) {
    if (credential.length < 6)
        return false;
    else if (credential.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

module.exports = router;
```

database/models.js

```
const tools = require('./tools');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    hashedPassword: String,
    salt: String,
    accessToken: { type: String, default: "" }
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);


function createUser(email, username, password) {
    const hashPass = tools.generatePassword(password);
    const newUser = new User({
        email: email,
        username: username,
        hashedPassword: hashPass.hash,
        salt: hashPass.salt
    });

    newUser.save(function (error, result) {
        if (error)
            return handleError(error);
        return { email: result.email, username: result.username };
    });
}

module.exports.createUser = createUser;
```

Comment: Not related to your question but in order to prevent [NoSQL-Injection](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html) you may use library [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize) or use at least `JSON.stringify(req.body.username)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

in routes/index.js use async/await like this:

```
router.post('/signup', async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        if (!req.body.email || !isValidEmail(req.body.email))
            res.status(400).send('Email invalid.');
        else if (!req.body.username || !isValidCredential(req.body.username) || !req.body.password || !isValidCredential(req.body.password))
            res.status(400).send('Username/password invalid.');
        else {
            const result = await database.createUser(req.body.email, req.body.username, req.body.password);
            if (result)
                res.status(200).send(result);
            else 
                res.status(403).send(result);
        }
    } catch (error) { return error; }
});
```

and in database/models.js use async/await as well, but also rewrite mongoose methods into ones without callbacks, with returns into variables, like this:

```
async function createUser(email, username, password) {
    try {
        const hashPass = tools.generatePassword(password);
        const newUser = new User({
            email: email,
            username: username,
            hashedPassword: hashPass.hash,
            salt: hashPass.salt
        });

        const result = await newUser.save();
        return { email: result.email, username: result.username };
    } catch (error) { console.log (error); return error; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not returning anything when calling the `createUser` function. Here a couple of considerations:

```js
// index.js
const result = database.createUser(req.body.email, req.body.username, req.body.password);
```

since the `createUser` is an operation performed on a database, it will be probably asynchronous, and therefore also its result. I suggest the usage of async/await to be sure of the returned result. Also, you need to change the code of your `models.js` file to return a Promise and await for it.

```js
function createUser(email, username, password) {
    const hashPass = tools.generatePassword(password);
    const newUser = new User({
        email: email,
        username: username,
        hashedPassword: hashPass.hash,
        salt: hashPass.salt
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        newUser.save(function (error, result) {
            if (error) reject(error);
            resolve({ email: result.email, username: result.username });
        });
    });
}
```

and than you will have to `await` for your result. You can do it in the following way:

```js
// index.js
// Add async here
router.post('/signup', async function(req, res, next) {
    // ...other code
    // Add await here
    const result = await database.createUser(req.body.email, req.body.username, req.body.password);
```

Comment: there is a return in the save callback: return { email: result.email, username: result.username }; I did try it with async/await as well (except without the promise, I just used async await in the createUser function as well) and it didn't work. it's probably something with the syncing but I'm not figuring it out.

Comment: btw as I said, the data gets written tot he database so the action is done even without async/await. I have also console logged the { email: result.email, username: result.username } object right before returning it and it's fine. but then something happens in the routes/index,js file and everything goes bam.